# Set keyboard shortcut for nested menu selection

Tags: macos, keyboard

Say an application has a menu selection Export in the File menu.  On mouse over, a sub-menu extends with the export options.  Is there a way to make a keyboard shortcut for one of those nested selections?

I've already tried implementing the keyboard shortcut for Export, setting it to Command-E.  However, this doesn't work, even though the Command symbol shows up next to Export.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [A similar question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/177574/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-nested-menu-item)

Comment: This also helps you when you have a sub-menu item with the same name as a top-level menu item, or to disambiguate between menu items with the same name. I added a keyboard shortcut for iTunes to "Love" a track via `⌘⇧l`, the menu item name `Love` was intermittently conflicting with something else, so defining it as `Song->Love` was necessary.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since Mountain Lion you can assign keyboard shortcuts to nested menu items using the following format:

```
File->Export->Sub-item
```

I found the answer in [this post on the Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20380162#20380162) by the user **macNtouch**.

Please notice:

- you have to insert the full path: partial paths will not work
- you must not leave any space between the menu title and the arrow

Comment: Take note: you have to put in the full "path". Partial paths will not work!

Comment: I use this for moving emails around in Outlook. Even with the full path I have to open the full menu path once before the shortcut works. My shortcut is `Message->Move->[Folder Name]`. It used to be just `[Folder Name]`. I was hoping that by specifying the full path I wouldn't have to open the menus every time I restarted Outlook. As far as I can tell, it's working the same for me with or without the full path.

Still, this is a cool tip for other times when the full path is needed to distinguish between multiple actions.

Comment: @AggieEric - My guess would be that this is because Outlook doesn't actually populate the menu with the folder names until you open it.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old thread but I was currently struggling with the same issue, in Filemaker Pro Advanced.

It turned out that if I put the shortcut in the "All Applications" section in System Preferences, instead of the Filemaker Pro Advanced section, it worked!!

This only applies to nested menu items. Non-nested works as they should (ie in the FM Pro Advanced section).

Answer (score 1):

MacNTouch's answer still works perfectly on High Sierra and Mojave. I wanted to set up a shortcut for printing checks in QuickBooks 2019 Mac, but just creating a keyboard shortcut for the submenu Checks… would place the shortcut on File Import Checks…

Using the whole path, File->Print Forms->Checks… now puts my ^P on the correct Checks… submenu. You must use the whole path and the arrows must be a hyphen and greater than, all with no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a shortcut to the submenu you can just use the name of the submenu as it appears. So if I wanted to assign a shortcut to the default encoding in Safari, using "Default" is enough.

If however you want to assign a shortcut to a submenu that occurs multiple times, such as "My Folder" you can use: >Move To>Notes, in Lion at least. This no longer works in Lion.

You could also try to assign a shortcut using apple script like this:

```
tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
click menu bar 1's menu "Shell"'s menu item 1's menu "New Window"'s menu item "Pro" end tell
```

and then use these steps to generate an automator action:

1. Open Automator and choose the *Service* template
2. Add a *Run Shell Script* or *Run AppleScript* action
3. Check that the values for accepted data types and application scope the are correct
4. Paste the script and save
5. Assign a shortcut in the Keyboard preference pane

If the shortcut for a service doesn't work at first, try running the service once by selecting it in the Services menu.

Credit for the automator answer goes to [Lori](https://superuser.com/a/252157/145616),

Comment: Specifying the menu titles like `>File>Duplicate` no longer seems to work on 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

Use "->"

Answered by MacNTouch at https://discussions.apple.com/message/20380162#20380162

Comment: What is the point of posting the exact same thing as Johan Kaving but a day later.