# Is there any way to define custom hotkeys for "deep" options, in system preferences > keyboard > shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, preferences, shortcuts-app

I'm using photoshop-like program, what I want to do is binding a simple combination of keys, to the option in 
 the app's command bar.

...but the problem is, there is another option which have exactly same name in different category; e.g, `Edit > Adjustments > Hue & Saturation` is the option I want, but `Layers > New Adjustment Layer > Hue & Saturation` exists, eventually nothing happens when I specify only `Hue & Saturation`, though the hotkey seqence clearly appears.

What I did;

- `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut > Application`
- assigned `⌘ B` to `*APPNAME*.app > *OPTION*`

then, inside `*APPNAME*.app`;

- `TAB A > ... > *OPTION* ⌘ B`
- `TAB B > ... > *OPTION* ⌘ B` (Same name in different category)
- and...neither works.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set keyboard shortcut for nested menu selection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58620/set-keyboard-shortcut-for-nested-menu-selection) It's almost but not quite intuitive… `menu->folder->item`

Comment: Yes it does!...but, unfortunately, hotkey does not work... I think this is the problem of my App. anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Try a hotkey that couldn't possibly be in use anywhere else, just to test. I always use 'big' stuff like cmd/ctrl/alt/shift/Z or similar for testing.